# How can I display this table correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am working on a very simple webshop, it should echo different products in a table of 2 `<td>` by 4 `<tr>` but now it only displays the different products downwards. Hopefully someone here can help me.

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from products");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $artikel = '<div style="background-color:#E3E3E3;width:200px;height:200px;"><a href=""><img style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;width:150px;height:150px;" src="'.htmlspecialchars($row['picture']).'"></a><br><div align="center"><b>'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</b><br><h6>&euro;'.htmlspecialchars($row['price']).'</h6></div></div>';

    echo '<table><tr><td>'.$artikel.'</td>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Use PDO and fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it display a table of 2 by 4?

You are putting every product in its own table, so the first thing to do, is move the `table` tags out of the loop and then you need to add logic to add a new row after every `x` products.

Although you don't seem to need a table as your `div` has fixed dimensions, so you can just get rid of the table and use css to get the grid you want.

Comment: No it doesn't, thatś exactly my problem. My goal is to display a table of 2 by 4 but I don't know how to display it that way..

Comment: @Thakkennes No need for a table if your `div`'s have a fixed dimension, just float them or use `display:inline-block`.

Comment: does it create a table of 2 by 4 if I do that? I'm sorry I am relatively new to PHP (although this is HTML and CSS).

Comment: @Thakkennes I think you need to do this in css / html, just put what you have in a containing `div` with the width you want and float the article `div`'s left and you will have your desired grid.

Comment: if I do this it makes a "table" of 2 by 3, do you know how to make this 2 by 4? That would really help me out a lot.

Comment: @Thakkennes adjust the widths / margins / paddings of the containing and article `div`s

Comment: Ok, I am going to try that, Thanks! **Edit: It worked! Thanks so much!**

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire code then you're missing a tr tag.
Could be a possible cause for your lay-out shifting.

Instead of using breaks, I'd recommend using multiple divs (or table lay-out if you're more comfortable with that) as breaks aren't always handled the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new table for every records, you can use one row per record.

```
  $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
       echo '<table>';
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $artikel = '<div style="background-color:#E3E3E3;width:200px;height:200px;"><a href=""><img style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;width:150px;height:150px;" src="'.htmlspecialchars($row['picture']).'"></a><br><div align="center"><b>'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</b><br><h6>&euro;'.htmlspecialchars($row['price']).'</h6></div></div>';
            echo '<tr><td>'.$artikel.'</td></tr>';
       }
       echo '</table>';
   }
```

Comment: This will put each `$artikel` in a separate row. The OP wants it in a 2x4 table

Comment: @Zoltan : This $artikel does not have enough data to be represented as 2x4 table. Don't you think so

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I meant all `$artikel`-s in a 2x4 table, not just one